# Flex: use of yymore()

Tags: c++, g++, flex-lexer

This is snippet from .lex file:

```
    /* Empty line just with the newline character signs end of
       the title block 
     */
<title>^[\n]{1} {
    yymore(); ECHO;
    // std::cout << "Text: " << yytext << std::endl;

    // ... do something with yytext

    BEGIN(INITIAL);

}

    /* Reads everything up to the end of line. */
<title>.+ {
    ECHO; yymore();
    //std::cout << "yymore: " << yytext << std::endl;
}

    /* Every title starts with # and text follows. */
#[\t\ ] {

    // ... prepare for html output

    BEGIN(title);
}
```

The goal is to read the whole text following after the '#'. According to online tutorials, `yymore()` should append content of current yytext to the last one's. Using `ECHO; yymore();` combo in `<title>.+` section shows the whole text. However removing the ECHO and using `cout` makes `yymore()` broken. Text is not appended.

In additional, I am not able to get title text in `<title>^[\n]{1}` section. Everything I got is just "\n".

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 5):

That's not quite an accurate description of `yymore`. `yymore` will cause the *next* token's `yytext` to include the current `yytext`. (The previous text is gone already; it cannot be recovered -- unless, of course, it was marked to be saved with a call to `yymore()`).

I don't understand what you expect this start condition to do.

The pattern which supposedly terminates the start condition is:

```
<title>^[\n]{1}
```

The `^` anchors the pattern so it will only match after a newline. (It's a zero-length predicate, as it is in standard Posix regexes.) But it's impossible for a pattern in start condition `title` to satisfy the `^` match, because no pattern matched in that state can match a string ending with a newline (`.` doesn't match a newline, and the `#[\t ]` rule obviously ends in either space or tab.)

Also, the `{1}` is completely redundant (it means "exactly one repetition", which is an identity transform) and `[\n]` is no different from `\n`, so you could have just written:

```
<title>^\n
```

My guess is that you didn't specify `%option nodefault`, so you're letting default matches silently echo without an error message. The problem is that the standard default match rule does not call `yymore()`, for obvious reasons, so the accumulated match is lost when the default action is executed.

Also note that `ECHO` echoes `yytext`; if you are using `yymore` (or `yyless`), then that is not the same as "the chunk of text matched by this rule". Consider the following trivial flex program:

```
%option noyywrap noinput nounput nodefault
%%
.    { yymore(); ECHO; putchar('\n'); }
\n
```

Sample run:

```
$ flex -o tri.c tri.l
$ gcc -Wall -o tri tri.c -lfl
$ ./tri <<<0123456789
0
01
012
0123
01234
012345
0123456
01234567
012345678
0123456789
```